# Change object function only for instance

Tags: javascript, object, properties, edit

I created an object like this:

```
var myObj=function(){};

myObj.prototype.prop = function()
{
     return "kk";
};
```

Then I create an instance of it:

```
var myIns = new myObj();
```

Is t possible to overwrite the function `prop` only for this instance like this ...?

```
myIns.prop=function()
{
     return "yy";
}
```

Is it possible, without an internal object function that does that?

Comment: Did you try ? Why not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work ok. Perhaps try the code before asking the question.

```js
var myObj=function(e){
    this.prop="kk";
};

var myobjinstance = new myObj("kk");

myobjinstance.prop = "kk";

alert(myobjinstance.prop);
```

**Update**

You've changed the code in your question. Here is the new code:

```js
var myObj=function(e){
    this.prop=function(){
         return "kk";
    }
};

var myobjinstance = new myObj("kk");

myobjinstance.prop=function(){
     return "kk";
}

alert(myobjinstance.prop());
```

Again, it works.